# Can I get Xcode for Leopard still?

Tags: xcode, osx-leopard

I just tried to upgrade my xcode tools on my mac running 10.5.8, but I didn't realize that the latest version of xcode will only run on snow leopard. I can't find the older version of xcode that would work on my work machine. Where can I get a leopard compatible version of xcode?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Xcode downloads for Leopard (10.5) are no longer shown on the main [Xcode page](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/).

However, prior versions are available from the [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) page.
Once you have logged in, you can enter "Xcode 3.1.4" in the search field at the top left and hit Enter.

Comment: That was too easy - can you find the download for tiger? Cause I've never been able too.

Comment: You're looking for Xcode 2.5.  I found it on the Mac development site https://connect.apple.com - log in, click on downloads, then click on "Developer Tools" and scroll way, way, way, down until you find Xcode 2.5

Comment: I wasted an hour looking for 3.1.4. Thanks for rescuing the rest of my evening!!!

Comment: This no longer works because Apple moved things around. Aaron Stephanic's answer does. I was able to start a download of the XCode 3.1.4 disk image.

Comment: Yep, that link of Aaron's has all the latest information on getting the older versions (and tells you which versions you need).

Comment: Aaron Stephanic's answer has now been deleted. For those without the rep to still see it, it was basically a link to this page : http://meandmark.com/blog/2009/10/downloading-older-versions-of-xcode/

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to download it using the interwebs (probably easier and faster than from Apple). The file is called `xcode314_2809_developerdvd.dmg` and here are some numbers:

```
143639af09af993d1f6ea45319ddcca0cf65df72 (sha1)
1107ccc98c79afb501f04f9ff1412a98 (md5)
```

Google is your friend.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the linkk for Xcode 3.1.4 i found:

[Xcode 3.1.4](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/download?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_3.1.4_developer_tools/xcode314_2809_developerdvd.dmg&wosid=791Kbomxhtnu2fpPx88gUoo6iEw)

(you need to be logged in as Apple Developer)