# Old Iphone sdk versions

Tags: iphone

Does Apple offer any way to *download* previous versions of Iphone SDK? I don't want to target lower Iphone os versions but instead install an older sdk.

Answer (score 10):

There are tons of links to previous iOS SDK versions at [this page](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html). Here they are, copied for posterity:

[iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with XCode 3.1.4 for Leopard (10.5.7](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1.3__final/iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.1.4__leopard__9m2809a.dmg))

[iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with XCode 3.2.1 for Snow Leopard (10.6.0)](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1.3__final/iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.2.1__snow_leopard__10m2003a.dmg)

[iPhone SDK 3.2 Final with Xcode 3.2.2 for Snow Leopard (10.6.0)](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.2__final/xcode_3.2.2_and_iphone_sdk_3.2_final.dmg)

[Xcode 3.2.3 and iPhone SDK 4 GM seed for Snow Leopard (10.6.2)](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_4_gm_seed/xcode_3.2.3_and_iphone_sdk_4_gm_seed.dmg)

[Xcode 3.2.3 and iPhone SDK 4 Final for Snow Leopard (10.6.2)](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_4__final/xcode_3.2.3_and_iphone_sdk_4__final.dmg)

[Xcode 3.2.3 and iOS SDK 4.0.1 for Snow Leopard (10.6.4)](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/ios_sdk_4.0.1__final/xcode_3.2.3_and_ios_sdk_4.0.1.dmg)

[Xcode 3.2.3 and iOS SDK 4.0.2 for Snow Leopard (10.6.4)](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/ios_sdk_4.0.2__final/xcode_3.2.3_and_ios_sdk_4.0.2.dmg)

[Xcode 3.2.4 and iOS SDK 4.1 for Snow Leopard (10.6.4)](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/ios_sdk_4.1__final/xcode_3.2.4_and_ios_sdk_4.1.dmg)

[Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2 GM for Snow Leopard (10.6.4)](https://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/ios_sdk_4.2_gm_seed/xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_gm_seed.dmg)

[Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2 for Snow Leopard (10.6.4)](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/ios_sdk_4.2__final/xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final.dmg)

Comment: What about later versions? Looking specifically for 7.1.2.

Comment: Every single one of these links are broken

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's bundled with all versions of XCode, but older versions of XCode (including 2.5 for Tiger) are all available.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596164/can-i-get-xcode-for-leopard-still/1596185#1596185).