# Client-ID/extension-ID mismatch when loading my extension in a new computer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension uses a client-ID that's based on the extension-ID it got when I loaded it in chrome extension developer mode. When I load the extension on another computer it gets assigned a different extension-ID, and so it doesn't work from that computer because there is a mismatch of extension-ID and client-ID. Is there any way of solving this issue?

I've looked a bit into publishing the extension via the chrome developer dashboard, but it involves paying a fee, so I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: See [Obtaining Chrome Extension ID for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually set the `key` value in the [manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key) to get a consistent item ID.