# Chrome extension authenticating a user

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, I want to authenticate the user based on email address i.e. I want the user to be able to access my extension only if his email address is from a specific domain.

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://github.com/borismus/oauth2-extensions) but I keep getting OAuth client not found error 401 whenever i run my extension.

The tutorials and instructions for implementing authentication in a chrome extension are quite overwhelming and confusing.

Can someone link me to some simple tutorial to achieve simple authentication in a google chrome extension.

Comment: You should use the `Chrome Identity API` to authenticate users. Follow the details here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity and [chrome.identity User Authentication in a Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044936/chrome-identity-user-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: unclear. are these email addresses all gmail/gapps? orherwise identity wont work.

Comment: The email id's are all google business id's. All are of the form ***.xyz.in

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044936/chrome-identity-user-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension