# Chrome extension user login

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to display a google login page as soon as i fire up my extension where the user will login to his google account.

I was able to display details of the currently logged in user by following instructions from 
[chrome.identity User Authentication in a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044936/chrome-identity-user-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension)

My background.js has the following code

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    interactive: true
}, function(token) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
    x.onload = function() {
        alert(x.response);
    };
    x.send();
});
```

However, I want to be able to login to my extension using a different google account than the one which is logged in currently to chrome. How do I do this?

Comment: Please keep the language tag for syntax highlight reasons

Comment: Why not fetch? http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch