# Invalid OAuth2 Client ID while chrome.identity.getAuthToken

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api

I followed the answer given in this question - 
[chrome.identity User Authentication in a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044936/chrome-identity-user-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension)

I installed the extension and copied the key from `chrome://extensions` and generated a client id 
[image]

[image]

After generating client ID and Application Id, I pasted them into `manifest.json`

My `manifest.json` -

```
{

    "name": "Identity test",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },  
    "permissions": [
        "identity"
    ],
     "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "575910104810-bip578sprqmaauj7cred8ejsf3cirs95.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
        ]   
    },   
    "key":"mebmekhndfhnahepihccnkiaifobgdbi"

}
```

My `background.js`-

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    interactive: true
}, function(token) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
    x.onload = function() {
        alert(x.response);
    };
    x.send();
});
```

But I am getting invalid OAuth2 Client ID.Reason?

Answer (score 2):

Your format of the `"key"` field in the manifest is invalid.

It's not the ID, but a cryptographically signed version of it.

See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/key) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development) on how to obtain a correct value.