# Chrome Extension Json

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

need to know if i can call a specific part of the following script

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    interactive: true
}, function(token) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
    x.onload = function() {
        alert(x.response);
    };
    x.send();
});
```

I currently use document.write(x.response) which writes out the users information but would like to call only the id

```
{ "id": "XXX", 
"email": "XXX", 
"verified_email": true, 
"name": "XXX", }
```

what I would like to do is turn the id into a variable.
var user_id = x.response['id']... Or something like that.

the original code can be found
[chrome.identity User Authentication in a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044936/chrome-identity-user-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: What's your problem exactly?  Are you getting an error when you call var user_id = x.response['id']?

Comment: Any reason you are using XMLHttpRequest instead of fetch?

Comment: If you're fine with the ID of the user logged into Chrome, you could just call [`chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-getProfileUserInfo), no need for an XHR or even `getAuthToken()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var user_id = JSON.parse(x.response).id;
```