# How to embed OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications keys to Chrome Extension development?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth

I need to do "OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications" within a chrome extension. So I end up using something like chrome.identity.

I followed this: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

I have this output:

```
{
  "private_key_id": "<Certificate_fingerprint>",
  "private_key": "<Private_key>",
  "client_email": "<Email_address>",
  "client_id": "<Client_ID>",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

But I don't know how should I embed it to use it with chrome.identity and if there is another way with chrome extensions.

Normal User authentication was like this:

Adding to manifest:

```
  "permissions": [
       "*://*/*",
       "identity"

      ],
```

and

```
    "oauth2": {
         "client_id": "***",
         "scopes": [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
           ]
       }
```

and just to call from background script

```
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken
```

Comment: You can use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(). Check this example of github oauth: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/github-auth

Comment: but I want to authentication with google API normally.

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044936/chrome-identity-user-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension

Comment: This one works with normal user authentication. My issue with with service account authentication.

Comment: its incorrect (insecure) to use service accounts from a client. your secrets will be exposed to all.

Comment: This is for testing, I will transfer it after that to server side.
Just I need to know how to do it.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147821/drive-files-api-and-getting-organizations-files-chrome-extension