# How to add the Chrome account name to an HTML element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a "new tab" page just for fun and to learn.

I want to add the user name (if the user is logged in) to a

element. I have no idea on how to do this

[image: that's how i want it to look]

I'm not asking you to do my work, but to guide me and help me with some documentation.

> EDIT: **It is a chrome extension**

Comment: Are you making a Chrome Extension? Otherwise this will, of course, not work.

Comment: Logged into what? A website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question could use a little more information** BUT — Login / Logout Authentication for users is generally a bigger job than you would at first think.

> Coming from a freelance web / app development background I generally consider an authenticated web app *at least* twice as complicated as the unauthenticated version of the same functionality.

You mentioned new tab landing page so probably you are going to be heavy into these docs on Chrome extension authentication:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Here is a little bit more on Chrome app authentication: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity

***From the above Chrome docs the steps your app needs to perform are:***

1. Add permissions to your manifest and upload your app.
2. Copy key in the installed manifest.json to your source manifest, so that your application ID will stay constant during development.
3. Get an OAuth2 client ID for your Chrome App.
4. Update your manifest to include the client ID and scopes.
5. Get the authentication token.

There are some great resources already on stackoverflow relating to chrome extension authentication, specifically this one:

1. [chrome.identity User Authentication in a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044936/chrome-identity-user-authentication-in-a-chrome-extension)

It looks like there are also others working on this same problem: 
https://gist.github.com/raineorshine/970b60902c9e6e04f71d

Hopefully that gets you headed the right direction.  Welcome to stackoverflow!