# Send a message to background script from iframe within a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a google chrome extension that has popup which contains and iframe. The iframe points to a domain abc.com. Is there any way I can click in the iframe and send a message to the background script of my chrome extension. I tried adding the following javascript code to my index.php page on abc.com.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"   charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mybtn").click(function(){
            chrome.extension.sendMessage({ action: "new message" });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse(){
     if(request.action=="new message"){
        alert ("Message Recieved");
     }
});
```

But it does not work maybe I am missing something. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `iframe`, you are no longer in the extension page context. As such, the extension API is not exposed to the scripts running on `abc.com`.

However, since it's an extension and a domain you both control, you can establish [External Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) between them.

Step 1: [Acquire a permanent ID for your extension.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development)

Step 2: Declare in your extension's manifest that you want `abc.com` to be able to talk to you:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.abc.com/*"]
}
```

Step 3: On `abc.com`, if the extension is installed you will have `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` exposed.

```
// on the website
if(chrome && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.sendMessage){
  /* At least one extension is ready to listen */
} else {
  /* Not Chrome, or extension is not installed */
}
```

Step 4: Send the message, using the ID from the first step:

```
var extensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, { action: "new message" });
```

Step 5: In the background page, receive the message:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
    if(request.action=="new message"){
      alert ("Message Recieved");
    }
  }
);
```

---

P.S. Please note that `chrome.extension.sendMessage` and friends are deprecated in favor of `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

Comment: And I can use the same method to send message back to the iframe??

Comment: Basica lly I want to setup two way communication between iframe that is pointing to abc.com and my extension's background-script

Comment: No; the page _must_ initiate a connection. If you need to send a response to a message, you can use `sendResponse`; if you need full two-way communication, the iframe should open a port with `chrome.runtime.connect`. See the messaging docs I linked.

Comment: Note though that if your popup is closed, the iframe will be destroyed and the connection will be cut. If you need a long-lived connection, consider either using an iframe in the background page, or better yet - WebSockets.