# Executing extension action without pageAction or browserAction

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a dedicated extension for my website and I was wondering if it's possible to have the extension respond to a specific button click only on my website. I want to be able to execute captureVisibleTab when a user clicks a capture button on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

1. Inject a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) into the webpage in question.
2. Attach an event listener to the button.
3. In that listener, [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the Background page.
4. In the background tab, execute `captureVisibleTab`.

---

### More in detail

1) Add a content script [to your manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration):

```
"content_scripts" : [{
  "matches": ["*://example.com/path/to/page"]
  "js" : ["content.js"]
}]
```

2) In the content script (which will by default run after the page has loaded), assign a listener to the button:

```
// content.js
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", handler);
```

3) Inside that handler, send a message to the background page:

```
// content.js
function handler(){
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ myButton : true });
}
```

4) In the background page, listen for that message and execute the code you want:

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if(message.myButton) { doStuff(sender); }
});

function doStuff(tab){
  // captureVisibleTab or whatever you want 
}
```

---

### Alternative solution

As abraham suggested, it's possible to use [External Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) to let your page itself send the message.

1) Add your site to `"extenrally_connectable"` manifest field:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

2) In your webpage, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` will be exposed if the user has your extension installed. You will need to [know your extension's ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development) to use it.

```
// website.js
if(chrome && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.sendMessage) {
  // Installed
  var extensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, { myButton : true });
  // Maybe do some error-handling in a callback
}
```

3) In the background, you'll need `onMessageExternal` instead:

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (sender.url == "http://example.com/path/to/page" && message.myButton) {
      doStuff(sender);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: You can also skip the content_script and [send a message right from the web page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: @abraham Indeed I thought of that. Care to add a second answer on `externally_connectable` ?

Comment: I would love to have an example as I just started learning yesterday. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @Dennis Added a detailed example (or two).

Comment: @Xan Thank you for the examples. I had a small issue when I tried to use `captureVisibleTab`. If `<all_urls>` is not specified in `permissions`, this error pops up: `The 'activeTab' permission is not in effect because this extension has not been in invoked.` In this case, `activeTab` did not work for some reason.

Comment: Indeed, you can't use `activeTab` in this case. If you need it for your website only, add only its match pattern to permissions.