# get link to published chrome extension page before publish

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Can I have a link to my extension page (in the web store) before I publish anything? I do not want to re-upload later for the sake of getting the link.

Comment: What do you mean by publish? Not uploading the extension to the CWS, or not making the extension visible to others? Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but:

1. You upload an item to the Web Store as a draft before you get an option to publish. This does generate an ID that will persist between updates.
2. You can upload an publish an extension as "unlisted". Nobody will be able to find the extension without a direct link.
3. You can generate your future ID without using Chrome Web Store, if you package it yourself to generate a `.pem` file and later use this file to upload the extension to Web Store. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development).

In either case, the final webstore link will then be `https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/[yourExtensionIdHere]`

Comment: This no longer works!

Comment: @MeeraDatey Which part?

Comment: The Link URL doesn't work. Returns 404

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Any published extension in the store right now works with the URL in the format at the end of the answer. Keyword: published. This question is about knowing this URL in advance, e.g. during initial development, *before* it is valid. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you Xan - I was trying to reach the URL before publishing, hence 404. I see that you must publish it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your google developer Dashboard inside the `Distribution` tab. make sure you have selected the following option before continuing with the steps.

- Unlisted
  Only people with the link can see it (Note: Item may still
  appear in web search engine results)

---

**Do the following simple steps**

1. just copy your extention ID from your google developer dashboard(it will be shown under your extension name).
2. Replace the last `extension_id` part with your copied extention ID in this following link.
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension_id