# chrome.identity.getAuthToken undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am trying to use `chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': false }, function(token) {` in a script of the options_ui, but I can't get it to work. I need the oAuthToken to change Data in a Spreadsheet via API.

I added the `chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': false }, function(token) {` when clicking on a save button of a pop-up in the options_ui, but I always get an error saying:

> "Cannot read property getAuthToken of undefined"

.

`options.js` which is included as a script in `options.html`:

```
SaveButton.click(function () {
                chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
                    interactive: true
                }, function (token) {
                    console.log(token);
                });
```

`options.html` is included into `manifest.json`:

```
"options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": true},
}
```

I added the key and the clientID to my `manifest.json` and I gave permissions to `"identity"` as well.

```
"key": "MYKEY",
"oauth2": {
"client_id": "MyclientID.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"]
      },
```

I could find out that it is not possible to use the API in a content_script. But as I'm using it in an options_ui, I suggest that this isn't the problem. I already spent a lot of time trying to figure out what causes the problem, but I wasn't able to make it work. Any other ideas? Maybe I didn't see something?

I already looked through other threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399699/chrome-identity-not-available-undefined), but couldn't find any suitable solution.

Comment: You can use `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` in background and popup scripts only. Use messaging from options page.

Comment: What do you mean by messaging? What would be suitable solution to send a text input from a options page to a spreadsheet? Any suggestions?

Comment: See [Chrome extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Also review the [Chrome extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the solution for my problem.

Comment: Happy to help. Keep coding!