# How can I generate .pem security file used to package chrome extension using c#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, pkcs#8

Summary: how can I generate key.pem file used for packaging google extension using c#?

As far as I know the pem file used in Google extension generated by using below code

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -out key.pem
```

and it's [pkcs8 key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development) , I tried to use bouncycastle to generate it from RSA XML file [like discriped in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086117/convert-rsacryptoserviceprovider-rsa-xml-key-to-pkcs8/27090675#27090675) , but the final generated .pem file dose not accepted by google chrome, it's structure is correct but length of the file is almost half of the one generated by chrome browser [in the packaging proccess](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging).

the final key required by google chrome is something like below

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEwAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKowggSmAgEAAoIBAQC0Bo/mh3bSiOiP
CUxtpa0c8IhDNJqaRDNWaKiqothEjgI7D/IU/uHacPotyedjzLFNr0cnhgguO4dQ
dNaSN+tAlgBqcexBbAl31+BEghNy+1PB189VNVSf8G+qOfF0SIKuBbb/+Q4TrvOD
XPrzulQpLcHMqRGqRE4PkT6574pKyiQGJvjeLBLEQtiobKkzoG3HOFkl9RsKae1f
Tuf8f25aVhKjoUyWp1mOfhHwdfT+76rmrz7F9X1s6M7pxigIfCiYPXHrWh02GTbj
EVLKTpVBg31JmrKErNJsv/j5P3wuSI12TCW4u1RXfahBHhi263oGCQ/2JO/Fm4+v
5wtX20x5AgMBAAECggEBAJjceZPlsp9SYSYTXzI7W6MXGpz2LdCP2IemlpFNdRXA
/2PnRkdNpbk19TisGC5FwMeV7XVB+fBH274Vd5zwnnFY7UF1OobSlbeNNoD1ck5P
2e7esM5JWnH0VtzUFpIGf/AEKj9v2uQbyenhKbWKoavVjpmZdcZ9+Up+qiR3oZWe
YiScMlYm5KL+pTD1IMZQ46DoxU17VhOVxbZoZOf+a5iAPtskjJyz12EOVldHASGz
VZkM54C+BrCTdJjOB5C7cth94D7J7nhgovBP0jz6A7WZtDpgBB6j1lFBwKSWw0U4
0LGZb/Mlb29txAoeR1YSHCe6RKuyyY3oas6fJ1kdRgECgYEA12r1nkK8fjNybMbp
No+TsWD9YDTLZrndHBMIR+GtUKWCXTpw7EwT0BCU4ATm6TiTje0ZI9kZW1tnbB4W
iCIyU8o/OeIBBbqKMLtk2iN82KFrNbIbA4IER0J441evYZTnh9NbkJks8iyATPdC
hypRiOi1V4n9CFDguGHj+IsKpLUCgYEA1fC65ASTYGhQ5iQ56G48iKV5XIBldKad
MFcaxzAA/Hp6GMywHqEiYvk/WmCakDmIK1g7Rf7LURvWTYp1nytRBzTRDvrf4ESU
WF4z5Mr6EcnqKEpqDO/tDCwUp+4BReXMrf99KXRAWYig9zjq8garYEmIznoIc02i
4Q/X1uu1RzUCgYEAxzQFxj/4hsuUeLrIVsgWz+Tc6eZoYapmqdt/wNkUqIslLoko
e5suhy2OPkrKLck/yfMDWH8eT7kKvpRkSac12v4f0asJPv7tY3snHAHNJZa/yXvW
Nzw4MJ1rpPAlIpvML3JoLiM3yQsV6haM0ulzVKO9biIQd2wzIs6DPgd15DECgYEA
lQ2vaAW4GEcVdgJvRfznt9xx/XyHMwqSIYfOZFCRn1ZFktmpKu3g40v8U59SkIFE
2c4THeUzCkN2v3dkE40+WuL1dJZdPAcLw7V+Oj0glRw0Q/X0hSbz5LMhgQ5VXLmK
LP//183it351h0jkh9MVu3QAGLr1AEBq5pr/KgH2vrECgYEAr6y3cCo/gdUi6v3Y
39B6LTcmqeKZbpqh3LzBl+I6Ke9t/TOqCZhwtuolMDkFLhZ9woGDeB1VBfV7yUW4
xyF3rE6uMSEZyD5ivku7VC2Gsz/2XuRGl8iToGXgGxzzg6HMQr6Hw36+0VFzzxSo
xn9/6PuHd1bNooOv1S3s0WVkTJw=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```