# What is the easiest way to find Chrome extension's id in a setup application?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, installation, chrome-native-messaging

I need to setup a native application which talks to a Chrome extension.
For that I am creating a setup, but I need the extension's id to be added in the native application's manifest file. That id says which extensions are allowed to talk with that native application.

How to get the extension id, assuming the user manually installs the extension by dragging and dropping.

Btw, To my knowledge installing an external chrome extension (no chrome web store) silently is close to impossible. I highly appreciate if someone has any solution for that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended flow would be to keep the extension in the Web Store (possibly unlisted if it does not work without the module), silently queue it for installation [using the registry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry) or other platform-specific method, and then warn the user to accept the install in the dialog on next browser restart. This is as close to "silent" as it gets.

If you absolutely have to distribute the extension externally (and drag&drop install will probably not work), you can pin the ID by setting [the `"key"` field in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development) for ways of doing so.