# Detect and test Chrome Extension using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, automated-tests, puppeteer

Is there a way to test a Chrome extension using Puppeteer? For example can an extension detect that Chrome was launched in "test" mode to provide different UI, check content scripts are working, etc?

Answer (score 28):

Passing `--user-agent` in `puppeteer.launch()` is a useful way to override the browser's UA with a custom value. Then, your extension can read back `navigator.userAgent` in its background page and identify that Chrome was launched with Puppeteer. At that point, you can provide different code paths for testing the crx vs. normal operation.

**puppeteer_script.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const CRX_PATH = '/path/to/crx/folder/';

puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false, // extensions only supported in full chrome.
  args: [
    `--disable-extensions-except=${CRX_PATH}`,
    `--load-extension=${CRX_PATH}`,
    '--user-agent=PuppeteerAgent'
  ]
}).then(async browser => {
  // ... do some testing ...
  await browser.close();
});
```

Extension **background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details => {
  console.log(navigator.userAgent); // "PuppeteerAgent"
});
```

---

Alternatively, if you wanted to preserve the browser's original UA string, it gets tricky.

1. Launch Chrome and create a blank page in Puppeteer.
2. Set its title to a custom name.
3. Detect the tab's title update in your background script.
4. Set a global flag to reuse later.

**background.js**

```
let LAUNCHED_BY_PUPPETEER = false; // reuse in other parts of your crx as needed.

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (!LAUNCHED_BY_PUPPETEER && tab.title.includes('PuppeteerAgent')) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);
    LAUNCHED_BY_PUPPETEER = true;
  }
});
```

**puppeteer_script.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const CRX_PATH = '/path/to/crx/folder/';

puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false, // extensions only supported in full chrome.
  args: [
    `--disable-extensions-except=${CRX_PATH}`,
    `--load-extension=${CRX_PATH}`,
  ]
}).then(async browser => {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.evaluate("document.title = 'PuppeteerAgent'");

  // ... do some testing ...

  await browser.close();
});
```

**Note**: The downside is that this approach requires the "tabs" permission in manifest.json.

---

### Testing an extension page

Let's say you wanted to test your popup page UI? One way to do that would be to navigate to its `chrome-extension://` URL directly, then use puppeteer to do the UI testing:

```
// Can we navigate to a chrome-extension page? YES!
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('chrome-extension://ipfiboohojhbonenbbppflmpfkakjhed/popup.html');
// click buttons, test UI elements, etc.
```

To create a stable extension id for testing, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877974/274673

Comment: I mistakenly thought CRX_PATH pointed to a .crx archive of the extension to load, but it is the folder where your `manifest.json` resides.

Comment: Also to note, navigating to the `chrome-extension://` URL can only be done after `--disable-extensions-except` and `--load-extension` args are added, as described in this answer.

Comment: What if you just want to click the extension button?

Comment: This isn't initially clear from the above answer and comments (even though they do state it) but you don't need to create a CRX file for a local extension you're working on. Instead, you can point the CRX_PATH at the folder you're working from, just like @EricMajerus suggests. That means the same folder you would side-load into Chrome using the Load Unpacked method. So for me, I ended up adding `const CRX_PATH = '/Users/alex/git/imdb-age';` to my setup.js file.

Comment: Can you show a sample snippet of button click being executed programmatically using puppeteer on chrome extension?