# Using puppeteer to test chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am building a chrome extension that is listening to messages coming from Chrome Dev Tools.
We are building a CI system and want to automate the following process:

1. Open DevTools and go to Elements pane.
2. Select  node (see attached image - [chrome1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMpcB.png))
3. Select the Accessibility pane (see attached image - [chrome2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hrUn.png))

Are the above interactions possible using Puppeteer? My other option is to use Sikuli (http://www.sikuli.org/), although Puppeteer seems to be the right way to do things

-anurag

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to work. Here's my attempt:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/puppeteer-open-console?path=server.js:25:3

**Update**

This prototype is just a test to see if you can open DevTools by triggering one of its keyboard shortcuts: Control+Shift+J. This doesn't appear to work.

However, one of the Puppeteer owners just told me that you can pass the `devtools:true` argument to `puppeteer.launch()` and that will enable you to open DevTools. Haven't tried it myself. He's not sure whether you can automate DevTools actions via Puppeteer. You might be able to get a reference to the DevTools window via [`browser.targets()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.4.0/docs/api.md#browsertargets).

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo code, at this point, I am looking into more than just a screenshot.

There are few pointers on how to test chrome extension at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089670/detect-and-test-chrome-extension-using-puppeteer, however, they don't go in the specifics of mouse interactions or looking for specific elements in the "chrome pane"

Comment: The screenshot code is leftover from a different sample. This was just a prototype to see if it's even possible. I'm talking to one of the Puppeteer owners now, check for an update in my answer in a couple minutes for more information.