# making a unique google extension key messes up the extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension I made but based it on some examples found online. The extension key attribute in the manifest, when removed causes the extension to stop working. is it based on a certain code I need to change or is it from the extension webpage(for say they only accept for certain key)?is there a google api that allows you to check for the key?

I have based my extension on google dictionary(by google)
can I make my own key where the extension keeps on working ?

edit: I want to know if it is possible to do such a feat?can we add a code javascript maybe to check for the extension key and identification? or it is from google where they check for a specific key extension?

```
{
 "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCuLnDgxFluQcqbOGrRJ2N7gYRj2DlTTnXa02Ho6IZNKm+Qv8cePlrsn/06irXeEPyikjoo9vokhsv54vV4Wb73x0a5K7s9pY2tuXnBzvik4Jru4KZozebnJTyYDAcjiyPc/ATrzlfQxlZiXIHBVj5KITnaFlR2SuxYkRVebPjUfwIDAQAB",
 "name": "Name of extension",
... 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtaining Chrome Extension ID for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23873623/obtaining-chrome-extension-id-for-development)

Comment: not really, cause I changed the extension key but still can't figure out why the extension won't work. I just want to know if there is a code that reads the extension key and doesn't allow me to access with a different key?or is it just from the google search side?

Comment: The linked topic explains how to change the "key" correctly so it should answer the question AFAICT.

Comment: I went through the correct way to change the "key" from the manifest but the extension still won't run properly

Comment: The problem may be in the actual code inside the extension so try to add [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question. Also describe "won't run properly" in more detail because currently it's unclear what actually happens. Assuming "can I make my own key" is answered by the topic I've linked the remaining goals at the end of the question need clarification or rephrasing/example.

Comment: And just in case, make sure you're reloading/reinstalling the extension after changing manifest.json.

Comment: Indeed each time I made a change I reload the extension, the code big and I can't make a small mcve without knowing where the problem is.

Comment: By stating that it doesn't run properly: the original extension is a dictionary, and I want to keep that feature in my extension. But when removing the key attribute, even though the extension works from the side I added/modified the extension slows down and the definition of the words won't show up as it should be.

Comment: You can get clues from opening chrome://extensions/ and clicking the Errors button (if present) on your extension. Or opening dev tools on a page, and trying to interact with the extension on that page, and checking the console logs in dev tools.