# Multiple chrome extension ids in firebase authorized domains

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am having an issue with authorizing my chrome extension. The first time I got this error:

```
Sign in error: Error: This chrome extension ID (chrome-extension://CHROME_EXTENSION_ID) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.
```

I added this to mentioned section and it worked. The problem started when I run the same chrome extension from another computer which was in another location on the disk, hence it has different id (unpacked extensions seem to base the id on disk location). I added the second id to the Authorized Domain list in firebase, but it does not work. It seems like only the firstly added id works and the following ones are not.

Do you have any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: You can [pin your extension id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877974).