# Auth0 in Firefox Add on

Tags: firefox-addon, auth0

I have a react application with authentication managed by Auth0.

I want to create browser extensions with users sharing their sessions between the web app and the extension.

I successfully followed [this](https://community.auth0.com/t/ultimate-guide-to-auth0-in-a-chrome-extension-popup/61362/7) guide and it works well for google chrome and firefox in development. However, the `callback_uri` needs to be whitelisted in my Auth0 dashboard, and this is going to be a problem for firefox since [uuid are non deterministic in firefox](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/constant-or-well-known-mox-extension-uuid-for-webextension/9701/7) and change at every install, so the url `moz-extensions://uuid` cannot be used as a `callback_uri`

I can't seem to find a solution, any advice ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, it's working for both Chrome and Firefox and I think it is even cleaner than the solution I was trying to work with.

Instead of using `browser.runtime.getURL("")` which translate to something like `moz-extension://[uuid]` or `chrome-extension://[uuid]` as *redirect uri*, and high level Auth0 helpers like `getAccessTokenSilently`, one need to use the **[identity api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity)** and Auth0 low level functions.

Here's a minimal working example:

- Step 1:

[Get an extension uuid for chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23877974/5324537)

- Step 2:

In your Auth0 application dashboard:

Add to **Allow Origins (CORS)** `chrome-extension://YOU_UNIQ_UUID`

Add to **Allowed Callback URLs** `https://UNIQ_ID_CHROME.chromiumapp.org/, https://UNIQ_ID_FIREFOX.extensions.allizom.org/`

The way to retrieve those URLS is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/getRedirectURL)

- Step 3: (pseudo code):

manifest.json:

```json
...
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "identity",
    "http://YOUR_API.com/*",
    "https://YOUR_AUTH0_TENANT.auth0.com/*" // ! required for firefox
  ]
```

Configure Auth0 (in my case using an Auth0-react Provider):

```js
<Auth0Provider
      domain={YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN}
      clientId={YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
      redirectUri={browser.identity.getRedirectURL()} // the important bit
      scope={YOUR_AUTH0_SCOPES}
      cacheLocation={"localstorage"}
      useRefreshTokens={true}
>
    <Popup />
<Auth0Provider>
```

Popup:

```js
const {
    buildAuthorizeUrl,
    handleRedirectCallback,
    logout,
} = useAuth0();

const cookie = await browser.cookies.get({
    url: https://YOUR_APP_URL.com,
    name: `auth0.${YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}.is.authenticated`,
});
if (cookie?.["value"] === "true") {
    const authUrl = await buildAuthorizeUrl();
    const redirectCallback = await browser.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({
        interactive: false,
        url: authUrl,
    });
    await handleRedirectCallback(redirectCallback);
} else {
    // ! we use localOnly because we are already logged out from the app.
    logout({ localOnly: true });
}
```

From there, you can use other Auth0 methods like `isAuthenticated`, `isLoading` or `getIdTokenClaims` if you need.

I hope this will help someone in my situation.